# How to add some default text to a input text field on button click using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, text, input, focus

Let I have the following form fields.

```
<input tyep="text" id="text_field_one" name="your_name"/>

<input tyep="text" id="text_field_two" name="your_friends_name"/>

<input tyep="text" id="text_field_three" name="your_girl_friends_name"/>

<input type="button" id="addToText" value="Add your Default text"/>
```

Now when I click the button, I want to add some default text, say for example "Hello" using jQuery.

But the default text should be added to only the text field that I was working with last time. I could not used focused because my mouse is focused on the button itself.

To make my question more clear following is the example:

Let I am giving input to the second text field and I have written "Paul". And let the default text that I am going to add is " how are you?" So after I click the button my second text field content should be "Paul how are you?" but the first and third text field should not change at the moment.

Is it possible to track that way. Or should I think in another way. Please I need your suggestion and help.

Answer (score 2):

Just store the last focused element of whatever type in a variable

```
var last = null;

$('input[type="text"]').on('focus', function() {
    last = this;
});

$('#addToText').on('click', function() {
    if (last) $(last).val('Hello');
});
```